# Download data from S3 bucket onto SageMaker inference container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I deployed a model to a SageMaker endpoint for inference. My input data is quite large and I would like to send its S3 URI to the endpoint instead, so that I can download it onto the deployed Docker container. Unfortunately, when I try using the SageMaker SDK to download the data, I get this error:

```
Read-only file system: '/opt/ml/model/'
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SageMaker Inference instance has a directory called `/temp/` which is writeable, and can be used for non-persistent storage. I used the S3Downloader utility in the SageMaker SDK to download data to this directory. For instance:

```
from sagemaker.s3 import S3Downloader
from sagemaker.session import Session

sagemaker_session = Session()

def download_data_from_s3(s3_uri):
    S3Downloader.download(s3_uri=s3_uri,
                          local_path='/tmp/',
                          sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```